# Trouble deep-copying a 'List<T>' C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am having trouble with deep-copying a list.

My main window, called `Form1`, has an instance of `System.Collections.Generic.List<T>` and I wish to provide the ability to edit this list through a separate `SettingsForm` which has an OK- and a Cancel-button. If the user presses "OK" then the changes to the list shall take effect but if the user presses "Cancel" then (naturally) all changes must be dismissed. To achieve this `SettingsForm` is meant to make a deep copy of the list, make any changes the user requests to the copied list, and then - if the user presses "OK - hand the edited copy back to `Form1` to replace the original.

To make the deep copy I am using the `MemoryStream`-`BinaryFormatter` solution suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129389/how-do-you-do-a-deep-copy-an-object-in-net-c-specifically) and my problem is that when I call up `SettingsForm` a second time I get an exception from my deep-copy function stating that `null` is not serializable. It is as if I had passed `null` to the deep-copy function but I have taken care not to.

Well, if you've read this far I'm guessing that you would like to see some code, so here we go; first the relevant parts of `Form1`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
...
private List<ScriptListEntry> scriptList;
...
public Form1()
{
  InitializeComponent();
  ...

  // Create an empty script list
  scriptList = new List<ScriptListEntry>();
  ...
}
...

private void toolStripButton2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  /* Will display 'SettingsForm' to allow the user to change the program
   * settings.
   */

  ...

  SettingsForm sform = new SettingsForm();

  ...

  sform.setScriptList(scriptList);

  sform.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then `SettingsForm`

```
public partial class SettingsForm : Form
{
...

private List<ScriptListEntry> scriptList;
private List<ScriptListEntry> scriptListWorkingCopy;

public SettingsForm()
{
  InitializeComponent();

  scriptList = null;
  scriptListWorkingCopy = null;
  ...
}

public void setScriptList(List<ScriptListEntry> scriptList_)
{
  // Keep a reference to the original list
  scriptList = scriptList_;

  if (null != scriptList_)
  {
    if (0 != scriptList_.Count)
    {
      /* Make a working copy because settings made in 'SettingsForm' must
       * not be committed until OK-button is clicked. 'DeepCopy' does not
       * work if object to be copied is 'null' or the list is empty. 
       */
      scriptListWorkingCopy = DeepCopy<List<ScriptListEntry>>.deepCopy(scriptList_);

      ...
    }
  }
  else
  ...
}

...

// OK-button
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  ...

  // Update the script list
  if (null != scriptList)
  {
    scriptList.Clear();
    scriptList.AddRange(scriptListWorkingCopy);
  }
  else
  ...
}
```

And finally the deep-copy-machine, line 11 below throws the exception

```
public static class DeepCopy<T>
{
  /* Used for deep copying anything.
   * Class 'T' must have [SerializableAttribute]
   */
  public static T deepCopy(object objectToCopy)
  {
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
      BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
      binaryFormatter.Serialize(memoryStream, objectToCopy);  // << Exception thrower
      memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
      return (T)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(memoryStream);
    }
  }
}
```

Creating the list for the first time works just fine (I've verified its contents) but when I try to bring up 'SettingsForm' a second time the exception occurs. The exception is 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' - "PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable"

Thank you for reading!

Comment: Is ScriptListEntry serializable? Have you tried testing serializing a single instance of it?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through to find any differences in what's being passed into `deepCopy`?

Comment: I had missed to make 'ScriptListEntry' serializable - see below. Thank you for your comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have trimmed the error message text - `PublicKeyToken=null` is the end of the assembly-qualified name of a type - it should look something like `Foo.Bar, Baz, Version=1.2.3.4, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null` - that is, class `Foo.Bar` in assembly `Baz` of version 1.2.3.4, culture-neutral, not signed. In your case, the error is that said type isn't attributed as `[Serializable]`.

Comment: I see, so the "PublicKeyToken=null" does not mean that I passed 'null' to the function, that makes sense! And you are right, I had missed to give 'ScriptListEntry' the attribute [Serializable]. It works now, thanks a lot!