# copy treeview to list<treenode> by value

Tags: .net, winforms, treeview

I'm trying to copy a list to a list, but it keeps copying it by reference, so a change in one changes the other. I tried cloning but it didn't copy the parent- child relationship.

```
foreach (TreeNode item in listNodesdestination) 
      testNode1.Add((TreeNode)item.Clone());
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is serializable, you could perform a deep copy using a memory stream.
[deep copy via memory stream - stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2001149/trouble-deep-copying-a-listt-c-sharp)